# Gujarati text properly not show on output video using FFmpeg Library in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, ffmpeg

Gujarati text overly on video using FFmpeg Library on Android

below my code in Gujarati text twin word proper does not show

I am Enter this text ="વડાપ્રધાનશ્રી નરેન્દ્રભાઇ મોદી." but output video in proper not show

```
 fun addFrame2VideoEditFun(
        videoPath: String,
        fontPath: String,
        outputPath: String
    ): Array<String> {
        val inputs: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
     var textFile = "વડાપ્રધાનશ્રી નરેન્દ્રભાઇ મોદી."
        inputs.apply {
            add("-i")
            add(videoPath)
            add("-vf")
            add("drawtext=fontfile=$fontPath:text=$textFile:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-line_h")
            add("-c:a")
            add("copy")
            add(outputPath)
        }
        return inputs.toArray(arrayOfNulls(inputs.size))
    }
```

my output video in below text show

[image: my output video in show this text]

Gujarati text properly does not show on output video using FFmpeg Library.

Comment: Can you give as an example of how it should look like instead?

Comment: વડાપ્રધાનશ્રી નરેન્દ્રભાઇ મોદી.

Comment: In Gujarati text,  twin words do not properly show

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.